# Stop buttons from duplicating from local storage

Tags: javascript

I am at the finish line creating a weather app. I created a button to clear local storage, and it works (click listener is in the HTML). However, when the user enters a city, and then renters the same city, it duplicates the button for that city. Furthermore, past the first page it repopulates all cities searched buttons even after the clear button cleared local storage. Where would I place the logic to solve this? How is it repopulating all cities searched when local storage is empty? Thanks in advance! Code:

```
let citiesArr = eval(localStorage.cities) || [];
saveStorage();


$('#search-button').on('click', handleWeather);

$("#city-input").keypress(function (event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    handleWeather();
  }
});

function saveStorage(city) {
  if (city){
    if (!citiesArr.includes(city)) citiesArr.push(city[0].toUpperCase()+city.substr(1));
  }
  $('#searchHistory').html('');
  citiesArr.forEach(city => {
    $('#searchHistory').append(`<button class="btn-primary" onclick="handleHistory('${city}')">${city}</button>`)
  });
  localStorage.cities = JSON.stringify(citiesArr);
};

function handleHistory(city) {
  $('input').val(city);
  handleWeather();
}

function handleWeather() {
  let city = document.querySelector('input').value;
  if (!city) return;
  let url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=${city}&limit=1&appid=${apiKey}`;
  fetch(url).then(data => data.json()).then(data => {
    let { lat, lon } = data[0];

    let url2 = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&units=imperial&appid=${apiKey}`;


    fetch(url2).then(data => data.json()).then(data => {
      saveStorage(city);
      console.log(data);
      let icon = `http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${data.current.weather[0].icon}.png`
      

      let description = data.current.weather[0].description;
      let temp = Math.round(data.current.temp);
      let humidity = data.current.humidity;
      let windSpeed = Math.round(data.current.wind_speed);
      let uvi = data.current.uvi;
      let name = city;
 

      document.getElementById('icon').setAttribute('src', icon);
      document.getElementById("cityDescription").innerHTML = description;
      document.getElementById("cityTemp").innerHTML = temp + "°";
      document.getElementById("cityHumididty").innerHTML = humidity + "%";
      document.getElementById("cityWindSpeed").innerHTML = windSpeed + " mph";
      document.getElementById("cityUVI").innerHTML = uvi;
      document.getElementById("cityName").innerHTML = name;
      document.getElementById("currentDate").innerHTML = moment().format("MMM Do YYYY");

        $("#cityUVI").each(function () {
         if (uvi < 3) {
          $(this).addClass("favorable");
          $(this).removeClass("moderate");
          $(this).removeClass("severe");
         }
         else if (uvi >= 3 && uvi <= 8) {
          $(this).addClass("moderate");
          $(this).removeClass("favorable");
          $(this).removeClass("severe");
       }
        else {
         $(this).addClass("severe");
         $(this).removeClass("favorable");
         $(this).removeClass("moderate");
      }
         });
    

      document.getElementById('forecast').innerHTML = '';

      for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        let date = moment().add(i + 1, "days").format("MM/DD/YYYY");
        let icon2 = data.daily[i].weather[0].icon;
        let temp = data.daily[i].temp.day;
        let wind = data.daily[i].wind_speed;
        let humidity = data.daily[i].humidity;

        document.getElementById('forecast').innerHTML +=
          `<div class="forecastCard">
              <h5>${date}</h5>
              <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${icon2}.png">
              <h6>Temp: ${Math.round(temp) + "°"}</h6>
              <h6>Wind: ${Math.round(wind) + " mph"}</h6>
             <h6>Humidity: ${humidity + "%"}</h6>
              </div>`

      }
          
    });
    document.querySelector(".hide").style.display = "block";
  });
};


$(window).on("load", function () {
  $("#city-input").prop("value", citiesArr[0]);
  handleWeather();
})

function handleClear(){
  localStorage.clear();
  document.getElementById('searchHistory').innerHTML = '';
  
}
```

Comment: Don't use `eval()`, use `JSON.parse()`.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, remove `eval`, use `JSON.parse()` instead:

```
let citiesArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.cities) || [];
```

When you clear the localStorage, you don't delete data from `citiesArr`, so clear `citiiesArr` with:

```
citiesArr = [];
```

Comment: I changed the  global citiesArr to JSON. So then I have citiesArr be an empty array in the clear fucntion?

Comment: The JSON change made it to where it loads all cities at first page when searched regardless of clear button

Answer (score 0):

When you add a city to `citiesArr` you capitalize the city. But when you test whether the input is already in the array, you don't do the same capitalization on the input. Do the capitalization first, before comparing.

```
    city = city[0].toUpperCase()+city.substr(1);
    if (!citiesArr.includes(city)) citiesArr.push(city);
```